# Is there a Version Upgrade provided for Combos.IComboOptions in ADO 2022?

Tags: javascript, combobox, upgrade, ado, visual-sourcesafe

We have upgraded TFS from TFS2020 to ado2022.

I have used:
import * as Combos from “VSS/Controls/Combos”;
Combos.IComboOptions
inside tfs extension.

It was working correctly till version TFS 2020, but after upgrading to ado 2022, on click of combo-box, it’s giving following error and asking for sign-in:

Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property ‘guid’ on number ‘10’
at Object.add (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:40879)
at HTMLInputElement. (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:40109)
at Function.each (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:3003)
at S.fn.init.each (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:1481)
at Ee (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:40085)
at S.fn.init.on (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:46578)
at S.fn. [as focus] (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:88550)
at t._onInputBlur (Combos.js:2:19100)
at HTMLInputElement. (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-ext-core-vnmGFvKW0VS9Hi4wcSHzACpdD-W_BY6jsM5wY0etaIbg=:312:217)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vx38JYf0FTtFkI9k88H54KYCLs9sIP_6xJwgWGnd-xvw=:3:43064)

Is their any version upgrade for Combos.IComboOptions too ?

I am expecting to know, if their is any version update provided for :
import * as Combos from “VSS/Controls/Combos”;
Combos.IComboOptions

in ado2020.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.